# How do I make types that can only contain certain properties in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have some code like this:

```
/* @flow */

type Options = {
  userdir?: string,
}

function foo(options: Options) {
  return 'foo';
}

foo({userDir: 'bar'});
```

I expected that flow would warn me here, that there is no property `userDir` in my Options type. But according to the flow type checker, this code is totally fine. How do I make types that can only have certain properties in flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your snippet, you're declaring an optional property, so Flow doesn't complain.

If you need Flow to tell you about the missing property, you need to remove the question mark :

```
type Options = {
    userdir: string;
};
```

If you need that property to be defined, but also allow it to be null or undefined, you can use a 'maybe type' :

```
type Options = {
    userdir: ?string;
};
```

---

**edit :** We discussed this on Reactiflux, turns out Flow (as of 0.32) just added Exact types :

```
type Options = {|
    userdir: ?string;
|};
```

Using this syntax, when calling `foo({userDir: 'bar'});` Flow will complain about the `userDir` property, which does not exist in the above definition.